# NullReferenceException on function call in master page

Tags: publishing-site, master-page, custom

I've got the following code that works well on most pages in SharePoint 2010; but it blows up on Site Actions > Site Settings > Manage site features with a `NullReferenceException` on the GetRootTitle() function. This is called from a custom master page (copy of v4.master):

```
protected string title = string.Empty;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
      // To ensure page behaves correctly, must call base.OnLoad(e).
      base.OnLoad(e);

      GetRootTitle();
}
private void GetRootTitle()
{
   SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID);
   SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID);

   IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(web);

   // Set a label's value to the title.
   sectionTitle.Text = title;

   web.Dispose();
   site.Dispose();
}

private void IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(SPWeb web)
{
   // Do your code for the 'web' variable here.
   if (web.ParentWeb != null)
   {
      title = web.Title;
      using (SPWeb parentweb = web.ParentWeb)
      {
         IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(parentweb);
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the error the `http://myserver/mysite/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx` page throws:

`10/27/2011 13:59:46.92     w3wp.exe (0x26E8)                           0x2334  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at ASP._8cc5acc7_8688_48f0_94fc_2a6d6124a691__164880475.GetRootTitle()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  aae55609-5b47-44c4-a883-752ad8cd2aa7`

**Update: For those wondering about the correct code, here it is (thanks to everyone's help!):**

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // To ensure page behaves correctly, must call base.OnLoad(e).
  base.OnLoad(e);

  GetRootTitle();
}

private void GetRootTitle()
{
  string title = string.Empty;

  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
  {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
    {
      title = IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(web, title);
    }
  }

  title = (title.Length >0) ? title : SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Title;
  sectionTitle.Text = title; // Set a label's value to the title.
}

private string IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(SPWeb web, string title)
{
  if (web.ParentWeb != null)
  {
    title = web.Title;
    return IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo(web.ParentWeb, title);
  }
  return title;
}
```

With the `using` clause, the CLR automatically wraps the code in `try/catch/finally` statements and will dispose of the objects correctly as well.

Comment: Where are you defining the 'sectionTitle' control?

Comment: It's a label further down the page, where the old `<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />` was in the master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Using clauses are in the wrong places.  They should be around the 'site' and 'web' creations in GetRootTitle() and you should not have one around the parentWeb in IterateThroughParentsAndStoreInfo().  The way this is structured, it will dispose of the ParentWeb object in the second routine, effectively leaving original the 'web' object in an unknown state when it returns (i.e. disposing of a parent object usually disposes the children too)

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Is that what's causing the NullReferenceException?

Comment: It can cause all manner of strange behavior but a null reference exception would be tops on the list of likely exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the answer to your question, but instead of all the iteration, you can just get to the root web title this way:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {       
    base.OnLoad(e);        
    title  = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Title; 
}
```

Comment: If all you need is the title of the RootWeb - do this. I'll have great sympathy for whoever inherits the code with all that iteration.